# ASP.NET Boilerplate - Custom repository no longer working after upgrade

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of asp.net boilerplate.
I have managed to fix all issues with the upgrade.

The only issue left is that my custom repositories are no longer working.

The error I am getting is "Context does not exist in the current context"
I have followed the tutorial for adding custom repositories but I am not sure if I have missed something in the upgrade.
The error is in the helpers provided in the custom repositories tutorial.

Tutorial reference below:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Using-Stored-Procedures,-User-Defined-Functions-and-Views/index.html

[image]

BASE Repository

[image: BASE Repository]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIXED!!

Changed

var command = Context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

To

var command = GetConnection().CreateCommand();

Must be some sort of change in EFCoreRepository Pattern